# Using Excel Built-in Functions in VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Functions like MIN(), MAX(), SMALL()..

It is too bothersome for me to write codes for functions above(and much more) and do the trick.

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code to use worksheet functions in VBA.

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.SMALL(....)
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for user defined codes. You can use

- many WorkSheet functions directly
- Use `Evaluate` as a workaround

  `MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("A1:A10"))`
  `MsgBox Evaluate("=SMALL(A1:A10,2)")`

Comment: @Excellll - thx for that. I tried but couldn't get it working (!) yesterday. I've never had this issue at SO.

Comment: My SO and SU activity blends together since I mostly stick to the Excel stuff, but I've run into problem with numbered lists and code blocks before on one or the other.  I had to use `<code>` tags, and as you can see, it's still not perfect.